# Lambda Expression for joining three tables

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

**Employee Table**

```
EmpID
Emp_First_Name
Manager_ID
Department_ID
RoleID
```

**Department Table**

```
Department_ID
Department_N
```

ame

**Role Table**

```
RoleID
RoleName
```

**Joining Three Tables**

```
var join = from u in db.TBL_Employees
                       join v in db.TBL_Departments
                       on u.Department_ID equals v.Department_ID
                       join x in db.TBL_Employees
                       on u.Manager_ID equals x.Emp_ID
                       join z in db.TBL_Roles
                       on u.RoleID equals z.RoleID
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = u.Emp_First_Name,
                           Department = v.Department_Name,
                           Manager = x.Emp_First_Name,
                           Role = z.RoleName
                       };
```

This Query is working fine. 
But I want to write the same query in Lambda Expression. 
How to display the same output using Lambda Expression?

Comment: Whats is the problem with this query syntax? Lambda syntax for `join` is much more complex and difficult to read as compared with query syntax.

Comment: This Query is working fine. But I want to write the same query in Lambda Expression.

Comment: It seems that the tables have well defined foreign keys - why not ensure these are navigable relationships in your model, and use `LoadsWith` to specify the eager loading depth, thus avoiding the joins altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as a succession of `Joins`, each continuing the preceding projection with the new join, but as mentioned in the comments, this soon becomes messy and difficult to follow: (especially if you are accustomed to using the Sql join syntax)

```
var result = db.TBL_Employees
   .Join(db.TBL_Departments, u => u.Department_ID, v => v.Department_ID, 
         (u, v) => new {Employee = u, Department = v})
   .Join(db.TBL_Employees, ed => ed.Employee.Manager_ID, x => x.Emp_ID, 
         (ed, x) => new {EmployeeDepartment = ed, Manager = x})
   .Join(db.TBL_Roles, edm => edm.EmployeeDepartment.Employee.RoleID, z => z.RoleID, 
         (edm, z) => new {EmployeeDepartmentManager = edm, Role = z})
.Select(edmr => new
{
  Name = edmr.EmployeeDepartmentManager.EmployeeDepartment.Employee.Emp_First_Name,
  Department = edmr.EmployeeDepartmentManager.EmployeeDepartment.Department.Department_Name,
  Manager = edmr.EmployeeDepartmentManager.Manager.Emp_First_Name,
  Role = edmr.Role.RoleName
});
```

(I've retained your original aliases for tracebility, and added new aliases for the intermediate anonymous projections using your pattern, e.g. `edmr` is `EmployeeDepartmentManagerRole`)

However, I would instead recommend that you ensure that the foreign key relationships which seem to be present on the tables are enforced, and then pull these through as navigable relationships in your Linq2Sql DBML model. With either lazy loading enabled, or with appropriate eager loading `LoadsWith` [DataContext options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith(v=vs.110).aspx) set, you will be able to reduce the query and projection into simply:

```
var result = db.TBL_Employees
   .Select(e => new
{      
    Name = e.Emp_First_Name,
    Department = e.Department.Department_Name,
    Manager = e.Manager.Emp_First_Name,
    Role = e.Role.RoleName
});
```