# convert sql join script to lambda or linq

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

how can i convert this script to lambda or linq ?

```
 select a.PayoutID,b.PayoutName 
   from [dbo].[PayoutsOfUser] a 
  inner join [dbo].[Payout] b on a.PayoutID = b.PayoutID
  inner join [dbo].[Users] c on a.UserID = c.UserID 
  where c.UserID = 16
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result= PayoutsOfUser.Join(Payout,
              a=>a.PayoutID,
              b=>b.PayoutID,
              (a,b)=>new{PayoutsOfUser=a,Payout=b})
            .Join(Users,
              a=>a.PayoutsOfUser.UserID,
              c=>c.UserID,
              (a,c)=>new{a.PayoutsOfUser,a.Payout,Users=c})
            .Where(x=>x.Users.UserID==16)
            .Select(x=>new
            {
                 a.PayoutID,
                 b.PayoutName
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Method syntax (= syntax with lambda expressions) has more functionality than query syntax. Hence I prefer to use method syntax above query syntax.

However there is one exception: When joining three or more tables the method syntax looks hideous, like Sebu showed in his answer. Is is also shown in [this answer where the two methods for joining three tables are compared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915844/lambda-expression-for-joining-three-tables)

Internally the Expression in the `IQueryable` is the same, regardless of whether you are using method syntax or query syntax, so the resulting SQL statement won't differ very much.

Therefore my advise would be: Use Method Syntax whenever possible, but for readability, less errors, better maintainability: join three tables using query syntax.

If you have to do the joining of three tables quite often, consider creating an extension function that hides how the join is done:

See: [extension functions demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

The following function takes three input sequences: IQueryable, IQueryable and IQueryable.
It joins the first two sequences on keys extracted using T1Join1Selector and T2Join1Selector,
If joins the latter two sequences on keys extreacted using T2Join2Selector and T3Join2Selector
From each matching T1 / T2 / T3 it creates one result according to the resultSelector

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Join<T1, T2, T3, 
    TKeyJoin1, TKeyJoin2, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<T1> table1,
        IQueryable<T2> table2,
        IQueryable<T3> table3,
        Expression<Func<T1, TKeyJoin1>> table1Join1KeySelector,
        Expression<Func<T2, TKeyJoin1>> table2Join1KeySelector,
        Expression<Func<T2, TKeyJoin2>> table2Join2KeySelector,
        Expression<Func<T3, TKeyJoin2>> table3Join2KeySelector,
        Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3, Tresult>> resultSelector)
{
     return Tabl1.Join(table2,           // join table1 and table2
     t1 => table1Join1KeySelector(t1),   // select the key from table1 for the first join
     t2 => table2Join1KeySelector(t2),   // select the key from table2 for the first join
     (t1, t2) => new                     // remember the matching records as T1 and T2
     {
          T1 = t1,
          T2 = t2,
     })

     // use this as input for the second join:
     .Join(table3,
     // use the T2 in the result of the first join as key for the second join 
     joinedT1andT2 => table2Join2KeySelector(joinedT1andT2.T2),
     t3 => table3Join2KeySelector(t3),    // select the key from table3 for the 2nd join

     // and use the result of the first and second join to create a linq-result:
     (joinedT1andT2, t3) => resultSelector(joinedT1andT2.T1, joinedT1andT2.T2, T3);
}
```

Alternatively join the three tables using query syntax:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Join<T1, T2, T3, 
    TKeyJoin1, TKeyJoin2, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<T1> table1,
        IQueryable<T2> table2,
        IQueryable<T3> table3,
        Expression<Func<T1, TKeyJoin1>> table1Join1KeySelector,
        Expression<Func<T2, TKeyJoin1>> table2Join1KeySelector,
        Expression<Func<T2, TKeyJoin2>> table2Join2KeySelector,
        Expression<Func<T3, TKeyJoin2>> table3Join2KeySelector,
        Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3, Tresult>> resultSelector)
{
    return select resultSelector(table1, table2, table3) 
    from table1 
    join table2 on table1Join1KeySelector(table1) == table2Join1KeySelector(table2)
    join table3 on table2Join2KeySelector(table2) == table3Join2KeySelector(table3) 
}
```

Usage is similar to how you join two tables using method syntax:

```
var result = a.Join(b, c,    // join your tables a, b, c

   t1 => t1.PayoutId,        // first join on a.PayoutID = b.PayoutID
   t2 => t2.PayoutId,

   t2 => t2.UserId,          // second join on b.UserID = c.UserID 
   t3 => t3.UserId,

   (t1, t2, t3) => new       // from the matching records create one new object
   {
        PayoutId = t1.PayoutId,
        PayoutName = t2.PayoutName,
        ...
   });
```

> I saw that your 2nd join was on a and c, while my 2nd join is on b and c. I'm sure you'll know how to rewrite the code to your needs

As the result of this function is an IQueryable, the function will only change the Expression. The query is not performed yet. Therefor you can safely mix this with other IQueryable functions:

```
var resultQuery = a.Where(t1 => t1.Name = ...)
    .Join( /* 3-table join as described above */ )
    .GroupBy(joinResult => ...)
    .Take(4);
```

The query is still not executed, until you do something that does not return an `IQueryable`, like `ToList` / `FirstOrDefault` / `Any` / ...